Is there any technique that I can use to achieve the required computation without reading all 10 million rows?
I have a data file from a Monte Carlo simulation of fifteen protein chains. The file contains 10 million r_end_to_end 3D vectors as rows and 3 x 15 = 45 columns.
My task is to find the exact row where the simulation stabilized. In other words, I need to find autocorrelation time. In other words, I need to find the Tau0 time.
Now, the problem is that the data file is huge.
So, reading the entire 10 million rows is not practical for frequent testing, plot generation, curve-fitting, etc.
Is there any technique that I can use to achieve the required computation without reading all 10 million rows?

10 million rows may or may not be an obstacle... how big is the file in GB?  When stored as a binary file, that is?

What algorithm do you employ to find $\tau_0$??

@whuber, Fisrt, compute the autocorrelation, then, curve fitting with nonlinear regression.

@jbowman, 2.91-11 GB, and there are 54 files.

I'd probably try something like interval halving with blocks of 1000 records, computing the first order autocorrelation, e.g., start with records 5,000,000 to 5,001,000, then either go to 7,500,000 - 7,501,000 or 2,500,000 - 2,501,000 depending on the results.  You'll have approximately 14,000 records read and be within 1000 records of the exact record at the end of the process.

@jbowman, depending on the results. --- what do you mean by this?

There are many divide and conquer routines which iteratively subsample with replacement. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide-and-conquer_algorithm

If the result indicates that the simulation hasn't stabilized yet, you'd go to the next higher block, but if it has, you go to the next lower block.  Think of it as root finding, where the "root" is "the point at which the simulation has stabilized."
